# Millions of categorical data + location and time to input in a LSTM. I did all answers here

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, lstm, categorical-data

I have the following problem and I have been unable to find an answer here or anywhere else. I have been stuck with this for long time now.
I really need someone help

I have a dataframe in python of 120 millions row in 4 dimensions that represent where a device ID is at a particular moment.
The device_id column is categorical while the rest is numerical.
There are 15 millions different device_id in the form of categorical data in this dataset
The dataframe is as follows ( first 3 rows)

```
device_id                    seconds      latitude     longitude

jg4M/taYRc2cBJPGa8c8vw==       752        53.392060    -2.069796
jg4M/taYRc2cBJPGa8c8vw==       753        53.392060    -2.069796
PdhyfpkIT8Weslb54thwuQ==       754        51.496483     0.116620
```

I have to feed this dataframe into an weighted ensemble LSTM

I can not une one hot encoder to transform the device_id Categorical column into a numerical one because will create a matrix with billions of zeros and the LSTM will give a wrong prediction
I try label encoder as follow

```
#transforming device_id into numbers
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
data1['device'] = le.fit_transform(data1['device_id'])
```

which give this results

```
device_id       seconds       latitude      longitude
7658              752         53.392060     -2.069796
7658              752         53.392060     -2.069796
4433              754         51.496483      0.116620
```

It fit very well into LSTM but it give the wrong prediction

I also transformed the long lat into x,y,z coordinates using this code

```
data1['x'] = data1.apply(lambda row : np.cos(row.lat1_rad)* np.cos(row.long1) * 6371 , axis =1)
data1['y'] = data1.apply(lambda row : np.cos(row.lat1_rad)* np.sin(row.long1) * 6371 , axis =1)
data1['z'] = data1.apply(lambda row : np.sin(row.long1) * 6371, axis =1)
```

Therefore the mistake must be the conversion from categorical data of 15 millions device_ID to numerical date using label encoder.

The prediction the LSTM network should do is about where the device_ID will be hence I can not ignore the column with the device_ID

I'am thinking to use auto encoders but I might have to input the 15 millions different device_id and I will have the same problem.
Also the result must be a vector that the LSTM is able to use.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much I really need help on this

Comment: this part I do not get: `It fit very well into LSTM but it give the wrong prediction`, how do you know the prediction is wrong?

Comment: Because I try to predict march 2019 with previous data and I can see if the prediction is wrong.
Everyone has told me that the conversion from categorical to numerical is the issue. But no one is telling me how to solve the problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: your example is quite difficult to read, the prediction variable is device_id? how can you have the same device with 2 different rows?

Comment: Because when was measure it was in the same location. You have the same device_id in the same location or you might have the same device_id in another location because is moving. 

The prediction is the longitude and latitude for a device_id. Meaning:
This is device_id is at this long and lat where will be tomorrow? 

But beside, I believe is the conversion that is the problem. Even I take out all the device_id that are repetitive then I will have around 4 millions of them.
Which we go back to the same problem.
Can you help me with the conversion or any other ideas? Autoencoders?